# Android SQlite, how do I check if the value in database already exists?

Tags: android, sqlite, unique

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_COURSES + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_CNUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_SUBJECT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_COURSE_DAYS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_START_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_END_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_PROFESSOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_COURSE_BUILDING + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_COURSE_ROOM_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

I want to check that if the course_id already exists in the table, then don't make another entry.
Thanks

Comment: You can set it KEY_COURSE_ID to Unique Constraint it will prevent to insert duplicate entry

Answer (score 4):

To check if a field exists or not in general :

```
 Cursor cur1=db.query("database_table_courses", "course_id=id_u_wanttocheck", null, null, null, null, null);
      cur1.moveToLast();
      int count1=cur1.getCount();
      if(count1==0)
      {
          //course id not present

      }
      else
      {
        //course id present
      }
```

Or if you want the **course_id** to be never repeated in the table, you can set that as the primary key and remove the primary key tag from `row_no`. This way you can simply insert a new row. If the course_id is alreday present it willnot insert and throw an exception - `SQLException`, you can catch it and do what ever you want.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting the data from Excel sheet and parsing it correctly in one of my activity. How do I prevent the entries to duplicate when the activity start again. This is happening in onCreate method of activity

Comment: @sukhpunjabi : put the code which makes entry in the if(count1==0) block.

Comment: @Ashwin 
db.query is giving error: `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'java.lang.String[]'`
Can you please post how to do it with `SQLException`. Thanks